# function component is updating props and state, but the value shown is unchanged

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using `react-dropdown-select`, and everything works fine, unless I create a new label.

Here's an example: I click below 'add kat'[image]

and then another form pops up to add a customer. Now, if I change 'kat' to anything else, like 'susan', the record is updated, state in my function is updated to say 'susan', but the text field itself doesn't change. It still says 'kat'. Even though the stored value says 'susan'

Here is my function component:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useCallback} from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import Select from "react-dropdown-select";

const SelectInput = props => {
  const [mySelected, setMySelected] = useState((props.selected != undefined && props.selected.length != 0) ? [props.options[props.options.findIndex(item => props.selected.id === item.id)]] : []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(props.options)
    setMySelected(props.selected);
    console.log(props.options)
    console.log(props.selected)
  }, [props.selected]);

  return(
    <div style={{marginTop: 20, marginBottom: 20}}>
      <h6 className="inputLabel">{props.label}</h6>
      <Select
        options={props.options}
        searchBy={props.searchBy}
        labelField={props.labelField}
        valueField={props.valueField}
        placeholder="Select or type..."
        values={mySelected}
        onCreateNew={(value) => props.multi ? props.createNew(props.attribute, value) : props.updateValue(props.attribute, value[0])}
        onChange={(value) => props.multi ? props.updateValue(props.attribute, value) : props.updateValue(props.attribute, value[0])}
        create={props.create}
        multi={props.multi ? props.multi : false}
      />
    </div>
  )
}


export default SelectInput
```

and then rendering it in a component:

```
     <SelectInput
        options={this.props.allCustomers}
        searchBy="name"
        labelField="name"
        valueField="id"
        attribute={'customer'}
        updateValue={this.updateValue}
        createNew={this.createNew}
        selected={this.state.customer}
        label="Customer"
        create={true}
        multi={false}
      />
```

In useEffect, I can see options is updated with the new Customer I just created, named 'susan'. Additionally, options does not contain a value 'kat'. As well, props.selected is updated too, and reflects in the useEffect function.

How can I get the name in the field to update accordingly?